# Disabling button based on child component state in React

Tags: reactjs, react-component

I am using a countdown component as a child component.
I want to disable/reable a button based on the state value of the counter, but I can't seem to read the value correctly.

This is what I have tried.
This is the countdown component:

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";


export default class Counter extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { time: {}, seconds: 15 };
    this.timer = 0;
    this.startTimer = this.startTimer.bind(this);
    this.countDown = this.countDown.bind(this);
  }

  secondsToTime(secs){
    let hours = Math.floor(secs / (60 * 60));

    let divisor_for_minutes = secs % (60 * 60);
    let minutes = Math.floor(divisor_for_minutes / 60);

    let divisor_for_seconds = divisor_for_minutes % 60;
    let seconds = Math.ceil(divisor_for_seconds);

    let obj = {
      "h": hours,
      "m": minutes,
      "s": seconds
    };
    return obj;
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    let timeLeftVar = this.secondsToTime(this.state.seconds);
    this.setState({ time: timeLeftVar });
  }

  startTimer() {
    if (this.timer === 0 && this.state.seconds > 0) {
      this.timer = setInterval(this.countDown, 1000);
    } else if ((this.timer === 0 && this.state.seconds === 0)){
      this.state.seconds = 15;
      this.timer = setInterval(this.countDown, 1000);
    }
  }

  countDown() {
    // Remove one second, set state so a re-render happens.
    let seconds = this.state.seconds - 1;
    this.setState({
      time: this.secondsToTime(seconds),
      seconds: seconds,
    });
    
    // Check if we're at zero.
    if (seconds === 0) { 
      clearInterval(this.timer);
      this.timer = 0;
      console.log("counter is 0");
      console.log(this.state.seconds);
      console.log(this.timer);
    }
  }



  render() {
    this.startTimer();
    return(
      <span className={
        this.state.seconds === 0 ? 'timerHidden' : 'timerActive'
      }>
        ({this.state.time.s})
      </span>
    );
  }
}
```

And how I read it and reset it in the parent component:

```
import Counter from '../Counter/Counter.js';

export default class Verify extends React.Component {
  state = {
    username: this.username,
    email: this.email,
    code: ""
};
  
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.child = React.createRef();
}

resetTimer = () => {
    this.child.current.startTimer();
};

resendConfirmationCode = async e =>{

    this.resetTimer();
    ...
}

return (

     <button 
         className="btn btn-primary register empty" 
         type="button"
         disabled={this.child.current.seconds > 0} 
         onClick={this.resendConfirmationCode}>Resend code <Counter ref={this.child}/>
     </button>
             
    
);
```

Inserting the counter works fine, reseting also, but the disabling of the button throws the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'seconds' of null
Verify.render
> 109 |     disabled={this.child.current.seconds > 0}
```

Comment: `countDown` isn't a valid React component. Can you provide a more comprehensive component code example so we have more context around what your code is and what it's doing? We can't see where a React ref is passed/set. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: In first render this.child.current is null

Comment: @DrewReese i added the full component :)

Comment: Ok, so `Counter` is a class-component. If you are attaching the `this.child` ref correctly then I suspect @gumingfeng is correct on the initial render bit.

Comment: @EricMitjans In React, Parent can only read state of children with forwardRef

Comment: @gumingfeng No, React refs have nothing to do with reading state, it's that function components are instanceless so they can't be passed refs and need them forwarded. Class-components happily accept them. See this [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-mestorf-w0tss?file=/src/App.js).

Comment: @DrewReese any pointers on how to solve the issue on my case?

Comment: @DrewReese thanks, you are right.

Comment: @EricMitjans this.child.current?.state.seconds, this change will resolve ur problem, but parent component will not rerender when child state changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `this.child` ref will be null/undefined on the initial render. Since you probably also want to disable the button if the counter component isn't available for some reason, you can just check if the ref's current value is falsey or if it is truthy and `state.seconds` of the child greater than 0.

```
<button 
  ...
  disabled={!this.child.current || this.child.current.state.seconds > 0} 
  onClick={this.resendConfirmationCode}
>
  Resend code 
</button>
<Counter ref={this.child} />
```

If we invert the second condition we can combine them into a single comparison using Optional Chaining.

```
<button 
  ...
  disabled={!this.child.current?.state.seconds <= 0} 
  onClick={this.resendConfirmationCode}
>
  Resend code 
</button>
<Counter ref={this.child} />
```

Comment: This solution indeed sets the Disabled = true on page load, but it doesnt unset it, when the Counter reaches 0 :/

Comment: @EricMitjans Your code `disabled={this.child.current.seconds > 0}` wouldn't disable it at zero either. So is the condition then that you only want the button disabled if the counter state is `0`? I'm a bit lost in your use-case at this point. Your question was about reading the state of the child component though. Has that been resolved?

Comment: The button needs to be disabled always, unless the seconds is 0. So basically the counter goes down from 15, button is disabled, when it hits 0, its supposed to be enabled. Your solution works by reading the first state, but doesn't re-render. I will have to find another solution I think. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @EricMitjans I see, yeah, parent only reads ref when it renders. The condition is correct, but because Parent isn't rerendered it doesn't see updated child state. Pass an "onTimeout" or "onCounterExpire" callback to the `Counter` component for it to "signal" time reaching 0. It's the more correct React way to handle it anyway.

Comment: @EricMitjans Example [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/disabling-button-based-on-child-component-state-in-react-dm3xm) with expiration callback.